# Should I upload a preprint in multiple repositories?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, arxiv, preprint

Recently we submitted a paper to the Springer Telecommunication Systems journal, and we would like to upload the preprint to a repository, such as arXiv or TechRxiv. Is it wise to upload the preprint in both? Are there any advantages or disadvantages to doing that?

Comment: What do the preorint servers say about this?

Comment: @user2705196 Can they talk? (+1 ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Advantages (minor): people who get a regular email about one repository's new papers will hear about it. People who search one repository but not the other or Google will be able to find it.

Disadvantages (major): it is confusing and mostly pointless. If people find there are two versions of it on two different repositories, they will wonder which is the newest one or whether there are any differences. A journal might prohibit uploads to one repository but not the other.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! We uploaded it on techrxiv.

Comment: I do not think version control is a major issue once there is a date on the front page.

Comment: Dates don't solve the problem. One repository's version might be newer but shorter and less detailed.